# Can I use glue instead of nails to install shoe molding?

Tags: installation, trim

I installed engineered bamboo flooring in my home office and have quarter round shoe molding to install to cover the expansion gap. Given how hard the trim is (I've bent nails installing the carpet reducer), can I use glue to fasten the molding to the baseboard? If so, what glue do you recommend?

Comment: Are you predrilling the nail holes?

Comment: I predrilled the holes in the carpet reducer. Used a 1/16 bit for 6d x 2" nails. Would using 4d x 1.5" nails help with pre-drilled holes?

Comment: Try using one of the nails itself to predrill the hole.

Comment: Have a nail gun, 3 in fact. They don't work installing bamboo quarter round molding. Love the floor which required 18 ga. Cleat nailer. No luck with quarter round. Looks like I will have to return trim and stain my own molding....not bamboo!!

Answer (score 5):

Shoe molding may have to be removed in the future to work on the floor or the wall. That's fairly easy with nails. It's fairly difficult with glue, unless you use something like hide glue that's specifically intended to allow disassembly ... and the techniques used for that would be hard to apply in situ to parts of a house.

Generally, don't glue anything that may need to be serviced, unless you're willing to risk having to destroy it to remove it.

Answer (score 2):

If you where going to glue it
You would need to use timber white glue from your local hardware. 
The problem with glueing is that you can't get the glue on the floating floor since it needs to be able to move. 
An another problem is that if you have painted stuff the glue won't stick as well

So saying that you are better off hiring a gas / or air nail gun. If you don't have one.
You will get it done in no time. 
An dont need to worry about making a mess with glue

You can also pre drill a pilot hole
Use a drill bit a tiny bit smaller then the nails. 
You won't have a problem bending nails this way.

Comment: I agree that a finishing nail gun would work fast and easy.

Comment: Just depends if he wants to spend the money hiring a nail gun. Next best thing is pre drilling the nails.

Answer (score 0):

We have the base already installed and are adding a shoe base to cover a small gap created by the floating and expanding and contracting bamboo floor.  We plan to glue it to the existing base that was attached with a brads and a air stapler.  Since it will be glued only to the base, not the floor, all could be easily removed.